# Python create a custom dictionary for NLP analysis

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-analysis

I am fairly new to Python. I want to create a custom dictionary to consolidate a long (1Mil+ row) list of messy company names into cleaned names. Can I use the nltk package for this?

For example: I have the below transaction data with merchant names. I want to create a custom dictionary so I can classify the merchants names to cleaned ones.

1. American Eagle#12455112 ---> American Eagle
2. American Eag            ---> American Eagle
3. //##7555Banana Rep      ---> Banana Republic
4. New York H&M                ---> H&M
5. H&M Chigago                ---> H&M

Comment: Try to give more details and attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you can remove/strip all non alphabetical characters from beggining and end of names. Would it be enougth?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I've added an example.

Comment: @Joozty some merchant names are truncated, others have locations attached. I would like to be able to roll them up into one single merchant name.

Comment: @Steve_Awu That is very complex problem by my opinion. You could for example parse all merchant names from wikipedia and then find matches in you data. I am afraid that is not just question of few lines of code.

Comment: You could create a hunspell dictionary.

Comment: @amirouche can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

hhmmm... my first try would not be with NLTK.  I would use fuzzy matching and return the result with the highest match.
There are many fuzzy matching algorithms.  The most popular ones (IMHO) are cosine distance and levenstein.  If you're new to Python, maybe try open source like fuzzywuzzy: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy

For example, take your transaction data and fuzzy match it against your dictionary list to find the best/closest match:

```
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    from fuzzywuzzy import process
    best_match = None
    best_fuzzy =0
    transaction_company = 'American Eag'
    for real_company in real_companies_list:
      temp_fuzzy = fuzz.ratio(transaction_company,real_company)
      if temp_fuzzy > best_fuzzy:
        best_match = real_company
        best_fuzzy = temp_fuzzy
    print best_match, best_fuzzy
```

Note that fuzzy matching can be time intensive depending on how much data you are processing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. My objective is more on finding a programmatic way to create a dictionary based on transaction data that will allow me to roll up messy merchant names into clean ones.